# Design question: Best approach to store and retrieve deltas in an SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, storage, delta

I have a historical table which contains many price columns and only few columns change at a time. Currently I am just inserting all the data as new records and this change could come 100+ times every second. So it is resulting in growing of table size pretty quick.

I am trying to find the better design for the table to keep the table size to minimum and the best query to retrieve the data when required. I am not much worried about the data retrieval performance, but it should be somewhere in the middle when used for reports. Priority is to keep the table size to its minimum.

Data from this historical table is not retrieved on a day to day basis.  I have a transaction table like *1 Current Design for that purpose.
Here are the details of my implementation.

## 1) Current Design

[image]

## 2)  Planned design - 1

[image]

Question:

1) If I use the above table structure what is the **best query** to get the results like shown in Current design #1

## 3)  Planned design - 2

[image]
[image]

Question:

1) How much performance hit this would be compared to Planned design #1.

2) Also if I go in that route what is the **best query** to get the results like what shown in Current design #1?

**End question:**

I assume planned design #1 will take more table space VS planned design #2. But planned design 2 will take more time to retrieve the query. Is there any case I assumption can go wrong?

Edit: I have only inserts going to this table. No updates or deletion is ever made to this.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I think you have better plan. You can use Temporal Tables that come from SQL Server 2016.
This type managed by sql to track change of table in best way.
Visit this Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks. It appears Temporal Tables are useful only if I am updating /deleting the rows. Here it will be only inserts. So in my case this feature won't be used at all and I will end up like we are using a regular table.

Answer (score 1):

I have s similar situation where I'm loading a bunch of temperature sensors every 10 seconds. As I'm using the express version of MSSQL I'm looking a at max database size of 10GB so I went creative to make it last as long as possible. 
My table-layout is pretty much identical to yours in that I've got 1 timestamp + 30 value columns + another 30 flag columns.

- The value columns are numeric(9,2)
- The value columns are marked SPARSE, if the value is identical (enough) to the value before it I store NULL instead of repeating the value.
- The flag columns are bit and indicate whether the value is 'extrapolated' or from an actual source (later on that)

I've also got another table that holds the following information for each sensor:

- last time the sensor was updated; that way if a new value comes in I can easily decide if this requires just a new insert at the end of the table or whether I need to go through all the logic of inserting/updating a value somewhere in-between existing numbers.
- the value of that latest entry
- the sensitivity for said sensor; this way I don't have to hardcode it and can set it on a per-sensor basis

Anyway, for now my stream of information is that I've got several programs each reading data from different sources (arduino, web, ...) and dumping this in .csv files and then a 'parser' program that reads these files into the database once in a while. As I'm loading the values 1 by 1 instead of row-based this isn't very efficient but I'm now doing about 3500 values / second so I'm not overly concerned. I'll agree that this is only true when loading the values in historical order and because I'm using the helper table.

Currently I've got almost 1 year of information in there which corresponds to

- 2.209.883 rows
- 5.799.511 values spread over 18 sensors (yes, I've still got room for 12 more without needing to change the table)

This means I've only got 15% of the fields filled in, or looking at it the other way around, when I'd fill in every record rather than putting NULL in case of repetition, I'd have almost 8 times that many numbers there.

As for space requirements: I decided to reload all numbers last night 'for fun' but noticed that even though most .csv files come in historically, they would do a range of columns from Jan to Dec, then another couple of columns from Jan to Dec etc.. This resulted in quite a bit of fragmentation: 70% in fact! At that time the table required 282Mb of disk-space.
I then rebuilt the table bringing the fragmentation down to 0% and the reserved space went down to 118Mb (!).

For me this is more than good enough

- it's unlikely the table will outgrow the 10GB limit anytime soon, especially if I stick to (online) rebuilding it now and then.
- loading data is sufficiently fast (although reloading the entire year took a couple of hours)
- reporting is sufficiently fast (for now, haven't tried to connect any 'interactive' reporting tools to it yet; but for some simple graphs in excel it works just fine IMHO).

FYI: for reporting I've created a rater simple stored procedure that picks a from-to range for a given set of columns; dumps it in a temp-table and then fills in the blanks by figuring out the NULL-ranges and then filling these in with the value that preceded the range. This works quite well although fetching the 'first' value sometimes takes a while as I can't predict how far back in time the last value should be looked for (sometimes there is none).
To work around this I've added another process that extrapolates the values for every 'hour' timestamp. That way the report never needs to go back more than 1 hour. A flag-column in the readings table indicates whether the value on a record for a given field was extrapolated or not. 
(note: this makes updating values in the past more problematic but not impossible)

Hope this helps you out a bit in your endeavors, good luck!

Comment: This looks like a good way to do it.. I will try to put more thoughts into this.